# What is */ in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, ls

Suppose you were in your home directory in Unix and wanted to see all the sub-directories.

```
ls -d
```

Would print '.'

```
ls -d */
```

Would print every sub directory.

Comment: The question is not about unix but about your shell (ie: command interpreter) and the ls command.

Comment: Does it really print nothing ? On my machine it prints "."

Comment: Essentially you need to have the `*` wildcard in there to get the behaviour you want because `ls -d` only lists the current directory itself `.` unless you use `*` to tell it to look at everything in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

From the man page of ls:

```
   -d, --directory
          list  directory entries instead of contents, and do not derefer‐
          ence symbolic links
```

So, I think you are confused between directory entries and directory contents. When you do

```
ls -d
```

The 'directory entry' of current directory is printed,, which is, in my case:

```
.
```

But when you do

```
ls -d */
```

You shell will expand * to all contents of the present directory and the above command will take each directory content as argument. Hence, the output will be the 'directory entry' of each 'directory content' of the current directory, which in my case would be (where `$pwd=/tmp`):

```
ls -d */
systemd-colord.service-XwkSsOM/  systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-XH1Bbsw/
systemd-cups.service-XRwwRXh/
```

Note the difference when I don't use /

```
ls -d *
a.php                            ip.sh                            systemd-colord.service-XwkSsOM        tmp.php
eiskaltdcpp-gtk.Wani.1462694194  model-one-final-rev.pdf          systemd-cups.service-XRwwRXh          tmp.py
hogsuspend                       res-failed.txt                   systemd-mariadb.service-XTsa5E9       yum_save_tx.2014-02-02.08-36.RhLlKa.yumtx
ip                               sess_ph2d61cksimbibrqrn1jru8l85  systemd-rtkit-daemon.service-XH1Bbsw
```

Putting '/' after * will filter out all the directory contents of the present directory which are directories themselves.

Comment: so * represents a string and / is a meta-character that works as a global expression?

Answer (score 1):

`*/` matches only the subdirectories of your current directory (not the files, if any). The `-d` flag instructs `ls` to print directory names rather than listing their content.

`ls -d` with no parameters will list the current directory itself (again, *not* its contents), which is referenced by `.`.